# how to print this in .xsl file?

Tags: linux, xslt

I have `.xsl` file, in this file I want to print **"<"** how I can **print** ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(...)
<xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text>
(...)
```

Comment: or `xsl:value-of` or `xsl:copy-of`... any instruction wich outputs text nodes.

Answer (score 1):

For Data you can use `disable-output-escaping="yes"` to display **`<`** or other..

e.x.

```
   <Data ss:Type="String">
      <xsl:value-of select="cd:Description" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
   </Data>
```